# Parse: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException"

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and need some help. I have created a user however its not passing through. I keep getting the following error:

> 2016-01-05 16:42:13.306 TwitterLike[5850:867865] [Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they are already signed up. Call signUp first.":

Can someone help me understand how to solve?

Comment: The solution is in the message.  Don't invoke save on a new user.  New users are created remotely with `signUp` (or one of the asynch variants).

Comment: post the code you are having a problem with and then maybe people can help

Answer (score 0):

To sign up a user in parse.com

```
PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.password = password;
    newUser.email = email;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
        }
        else {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3, this happens when you use, .saveInBackground instead of .SignUPInBackground

Just had this problem my self. Typos are everything  in this world!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my experience with using Parse with Swift3:

```
let user = PFUser()
user.email = emailTextField.text
user.username = emailTextField.text
user.password = passwordTextField.text

user.signUpInBackground(block: { (signed, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error)
                }
                else{
                    print("signed up")
                }
            })
```